# Can no longer modifiying priceset amounts in hooks in 5.1.2

Tags: price-sets

I'm looking for help on adjusting a priceset amount in a hook at the end of a membership signup.
Until now under 4.7 for reasons of multi-level priceset complexity I've been adjusting priceset amounts via the hook_civicrm_validateForm by adjusting the values in the $form object. This has been working fine, but this is now longing working in 5.1.2. 
I realise that strictly speaking I shouldn't modify the $form in the validateForm hook.
"The hook is intended for validation rather than altering form values."
However I can't see anywhere else to change the amounts.
I have two questions, i) Can anyone explain the difference in behaivour between 4.7 and 5.1.2? ii) is there a better place or method to adjust the priceset amount?

Comment: Did you ever try the buildAmount hook?

Comment: Hi,
if I'm not mistaken buildAmount is called even before buildForm. I need to adjust the priceset amount taking into account fields adjusted by the user in the form interface.
So I need to intervine at the time of submitting the form.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Build Amount](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildAmount/) hook to alter the price. If you want to trigger the change on form submit than you can use $form->_flagSubmitted. This is set to true when form is submitted. You can also use [buildform](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) or [post process](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_postProcess/) hook. But validateForm is a bad option.

```
function xxx_civicrm_buildAmount($pageType, &$form, &$amount) {
  if (get_class($form) == 'CRM_Event_Form_Registration_Register' && $form->_flagSubmitted) { 
    foreach ($amount as $key =$value) {
      foreach ($value['options'] as $pid =$value) {
        $amount[$key]['options'][$pid]['amount'] = $value['amount'] - ($value['amount'] * 0.1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Hi Pradeep,
Interesting, I've now got the code executing in buildAmount as you suggested with the _flagSubmitted = true.
The $form is being updated but the changes still aren't being transferred to the database.
Here's the $form record I'm trying to update which worked before.
$form->_priceSet['fields'][$priceset_id]['options'][$pricefield_id]['amount'] = $amount;
R

Comment: use $amount variable to update the price.(updated ans to add smaple code snippet)

Comment: Thanks  I've put it into place... $amount is correctly updated, but the values still aren't going into the database... zero in civicrm_financial_item.

Comment: Can you provide code snippet?

Comment: <code> function hooks_civicrm_buildAmount( $pageType, &$form, &$amount ){
 if($form->_flagSubmitted){

    $priceset_fed = $form->_submitValues['priceset_fed'];
    $pricefield_fed = $form->_submitValues['pricefield_fed'];
    $priceset_club = $form->_submitValues['priceset_club'];
    $pricefield_club = $form->_submitValues['pricefield_club'];
    $amount[$priceset_fed]['options'][$pricefield_fed]['amount'] = $form->_submitValues['montant_quotepart_fed'];
   $amount[$priceset_club]['options'][$pricefield_club]['amount'] = $form->_submitValues['montant_quotepart_club'];
   }
}</code>

Comment: Sorry for the layout, I'm having problems with the code tag.

Comment: you doing it wrong. You need to have the price option selected in  $form->_submitValues i.e in $form->_params which will be used to calculate total amount. Since you setting this only on main form i feel those values are not available on Confirm. You probably might have to use PostProcess hook as well.

Comment: I can confirm that the price options are selected in _submitValues
price_2618 (String, 4 characters ) 9167
"use PostProcess hook as well"..? Set which values in PostProcess.
Thanks for your help...

Comment: I am not sure, you might need to add a condition in buildAmount hook as   if (get_class($form) == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main' && $form->_flagSubmitted) {